# My table contents disappeared whenever I clicked the button using streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I have the streamlit code as below.

I have the sidebar and when I click the sidebar, the contents can be downloaded via the `rest api`. Since the contents are relatively large, I tried to paginate them in the table.

The problem is that when I changed the page by clicking the `+` or `-` icon, the contents in the table disappeared.

How to resolve this issue?

Below is my code.

```
import boto3
import requests
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


class SessionState:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


def get_session_state():
    if 'session_state' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.session_state = SessionState()
    return st.session_state.session_state


@st.cache_data(show_spinner=False)
def load_data(base_url, query_params):
    try:
        response = requests.get(base_url, params=query_params)
        response_data = response.json()
        return pd.DataFrame(response_data)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
       


def s3_int_tier():
    state = get_session_state()
    bucket = st.selectbox("버킷 선택", ['json1', 'json2', 'test'])

    if bucket == "json1":
        bucket_name = "my-bucket"
        resp = list_obj(s3, bucket_name, "")
        tier_1 = [it['Prefix'].split("/")[0] for it in resp['CommonPrefixes']]
        t1 = st.selectbox("tier_1", [None] + tier_1)
        tier_2 = []
        if t1 is not None:
            resp = list_obj(s3, bucket_name, tier_1)
            tier_2 = [it['Prefix'].split("/")[1] for it in resp['CommonPrefixes']]
        t2 = st.selectbox("tier_2", [None] + tier_2)

        if st.button("Go Search") and all((t1,t2)):
            with st.spinner("Loading..."):
                base_url = "https://qnee82b0d.....(my api)"  
                query_params = {
                    "tier1": t1,
                    "tier2": t2,
                }
                data = load_data(base_url, query_params)

                # state
                state.bucket_index = bucket.index(bucket)
                state.tier1_index = t1
                state.tier2_index = t2


                page_size = 10
                page_number = st.number_input('Page', min_value=1, max_value=(len(data) // page_size) + 1, value=1)

                state.page_number = page_number
                start_idx = (page_number - 1) * page_size
                end_idx = min(start_idx + page_size, len(data))
                st.table(data.iloc[start_idx:end_idx])


def main():
    options = ['menu1', 'menu2', 'menu3', 'menu4']
    menu_option = st.sidebar.selectbox('Aqua API', (options[0], options[1], options[2], options[3]))

    if menu_option == options[0]:
        s3_int_tier()


def list_obj(s3, bucket, serviceid="", eventtype=""):
    if serviceid == "":
        prefix = ""
    elif eventtype == "":
        prefix = "/".join([serviceid])
        prefix = prefix + "/"
    resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/')
    return resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you share a runnable code snippet so we can reproduce this issue? We won't be able to run this snippet since we don't have access to your S3 account